# Phonegap and Android overflow issue

Tags: android, css, cordova, overflow

It seems that Android webview does not care at all about `overflow:hidden` css property when having overflowing divs. I took the code of a great [tutorial on GPU transitions with HTML/CSS](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/03/hardware-accelerated-page-transitions-for-mobile-web-apps-phonegap-apps/) and add it to a simple phonegap project ([github](https://github.com/htulipe/phonegap-sliding-transition)).

This code defines two 100% width divs where one overflows the screen on the right side. Clicking on links makes an GPU acelerated transition that moves the divs.

Despite the [included css](https://github.com/htulipe/phonegap-sliding-transition/blob/master/www/index.html#L6), one can drag the whole content to the side and thus display the right div unwillingly.

Any thoughts on that?

Thanks

PS: May I precise that I tried most of commonly proposed answereds to overflow issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I figured out how to do it, this is not pretty but has the advantage of really working:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

In current Chrome versions, cancel the touchmove/touchstart events is not allowed for performace reasons. Intead you can try to set `touch-action: none;` on the body tag.