# Is it possible to control the scrolling of a page?

Tags: html, css, iframe, phonegap

I have an HTML page with an iframe like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>Page</h1>
    <iframe src="./randompage.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
```

However, the page itself scrolls and the iframe also scrolls. Is there a way to stop the page scrolling and have only the iframe which scrolls?

(Note that this is for a phonegap app)

---

### Extra Information

It seems that `body { overflow: hidden; }` doesn't work on phonegap (see here: [Phonegap and Android overflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19292799/phonegap-and-android-overflow-issue)).

Comment: Have you tried using `body{overflow-y: hidden};` ?

Comment: @Rubenxfd Hmm no, I didn't think of that... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow-y: hidden` to stop your page from (vertical) scrolling. You could add this to your `body` like this

```
body{
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ma71zLd/)

If you want to disable both vertical and horizontal scrolling, you can use `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to make sure the content [fits inside the viewport](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwZwXw).

If that's not an option, [trim the body by hiding the overflow](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXdXKw).

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `overflow:hidden` does not work in your case, you could, depending on your exact use case, make the iframe `position:absolute` and define it's position via `left` and `top`. This would mean the parenting page does not overflow beyond the viewport.